# Jumping without rigidbody in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to add jumping to the controls of our control script but it just doesn't work yet and I'm getting kind of frustrated because I tried a lot to make it work. I don't use rigidbodies and rather want to use script based physics and - but later - raycasts (to detect ground). It's 3D but with a fixed perspective because the characters are sprites (we are thinking about trying a style similar to Don't Starve, Paper Mario etc.). And the thing I want to put in for now is to jump upwards when the character stands still and later on jumps that also let the character travel a bit of distance when the character moves. Well, you get the picture. For that I first need to get jumping working at all - and also gravity to put the character back down while also considering that the character could land on a ground that has a different height than the starting ground.
What happens now is that the character jumps just a tiny little bit, like not even a hop, and then falls down endlessly - or goes up endlessly when jump is pressed again. So, how do I fix that?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Controls3D : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float player3DSpeed = 5f;
    private bool IsGrounded = true;
    private const float groundY = (float) 0.4;
    private Vector3 Velocity = Vector3.zero;
    public Vector3 gravity = new Vector3(0, -10, 0);

    void Start()
    {
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (IsGrounded)
        {
            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
            {
                IsGrounded = false;
                Velocity = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 20, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
            }
            Velocity.x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
            Velocity.z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
            if (Velocity.sqrMagnitude > 1)
                Velocity.Normalize();
            transform.position += Velocity * player3DSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        else
        {
            Velocity += gravity * Time.deltaTime;
            Vector3 position = transform.position + Velocity * Time.deltaTime;
            if (position.y < groundY)
            {
                position.y = groundY;
                IsGrounded = true;
            }
            transform.position = position;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The falling down endlessly problem is solved. Just had to set Velocity.y = 0; after the transform.position = position; under IsGrounded = true;

Comment: If you step through I bet you'll see the initial velocity is smaller than you thought because of `Velocity.Normalize();`, so your Velocity.y is some number between -1 and 1. I think your upward velocity should be independent of the other two directions, or, you should probably normalize the velocity every single time you modify it instead of only when grounded. I.e., why are normalizing in the grounded case but not here: `Velocity += gravity * Time.deltaTime;`?

Comment: I think I got something now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If i were you, i think i wouldve changed the whole thing into a character controller, as this simplifies the process, a ####ton :P

If you figure out you do want to use the CC. This is the solution i usually use:

```
CharacterController controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    // is the controller on the ground?
    if (controller.isGrounded)
    {
        //Feed moveDirection with input.
        moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);



        //Multiply it by speed.
        moveDirection *= speed;
        //Jumping
        if (Input.GetButton("Jump"))
            moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;

    }
    //Applying gravity to the controller
    moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    //Making the character move
    controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
```

moveDirection is a Vector3 Type variable, and speed and jumpSpeed are public float values used to modify the speed.

Please NOTE: Character Controllers, let you program your own Physics.